# How to solve this logic problem on flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

[image]

I've tried to make a button called 'next' and wanted the app to show the other page.
But UI just shows the button called 'next' and when I click the button, nothing happens.
How can I solve this problem?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you post your entire code

Comment: weird. Post the entire code instead of screenshot.

Comment: Don't know how to attach a code.
I tried but couldn't figure it out... @Doc

Comment: paste your code. select all the code and press `Ctrl+K`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor the `MaterialApp` into a separate widget.

```
class App extends StatelessWidget{
    build(context){
        return MaterialApp(home:First());
    }
}

class First extends StatelessWidget{
    build(context){
        return Scaffold();//add button to navigate to other page
    }
}

class Second extends StatelessWidget{
    build(context){
        return Scaffold();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `key: UniqueKey()` property to two scaffolds